# How to add `~/.config/nvim' into runtime path for Lua?

Tags: neovim, lua

In my `init.lua` I call:

```
require('plugins')
require('theme')
```

This works when editing in the `~/.config/nvim` directory, where `init.lua`, `plugins.lua` and `theme.lua` are located.

But when I run vim outside of this directory, I get the following error:

```
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: /home/miki/.config/nvim/init.lua:5: module 'plugins' n
ot found:
        no field package.preload['plugins']
        no file './plugins.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta3/plugins.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/plugins.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/plugins/init.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/plugins.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/plugins/init.lua'
        no file './plugins.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/plugins.so'
        no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.1/plugins.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
```

How do I add `~/.config/nvim` to the places Lua looks for modules?

I also tried to put these modules into `~/.config/nvim/lua` folder, but then they were not found even in the `init.lua`.

Answer (score 4):

Removing the following lines from my `init.lua`

```
vim.cmd [[set runtimepath=$VIMRUNTIME]]
vim.cmd [[set packpath=~/.local/share/nvim/site]]
```

and placing all my .lua modules (except `init.lua`) into `~/.config/nvim/lua` fixed the issue.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! For the record, rather than delete and post a modified answer, we encourage you to make use of the [edit] button.

Comment: I didn't modify it. I thought my change work, posted it, immediately realized I celebrated prematurely, deleted the answer and later found a new solution which I posted...